# Why the need for browserify `paths` definition?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, gulp, browserify

The link https://github.com/jhades/angularjs-gulp-example/blob/master/gulpfile.js has the gulp `build-js` task definition using browserify `paths`. I don't understand the need for it... wasn't it possible just to specify the entries as `entries: './js/**/*.js',` and this would have caused it to search all the sub-directories as well... instead of explicitly specifying `paths: ['./js/controllers', './js/services', './js/directives'],` which are all sub-directories of the same parent?

Any hints appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author is using the `paths` configuration to enable non-relative `require` calls like [these](https://github.com/jhades/angularjs-gulp-example/blob/b4c9dad66ccb234fbee4a8329fc56874f66e7bce/js/app.js#L36-L40):

```
require('todoCtrl');
require('todoStorage');
require('todoFocus');
require('todoEscape');
require('footer');
```

Browserify emulates Node's module resolution mechanism (which is explained [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together)) and when Node resolves a non-relative `require`, it looks in `node_modules`. The `paths` option gives Browserify a list of paths that are not in `node_modules` that it should check (*before* checking `node_modules`) when attempting to resolve non-relative `require` calls.

If all of your `require` calls for modules in your own project use relative paths (e.g. `require('./js/controllers/todoCtrl')`), you won't need the `paths` configuration option.

Comment: I am actually a little confused now. Maybe I should go back to the drawing board. Can somebody explain to me what `entries` is doing exactly? Is it looking for the javascript files to convert or is it actually specifying the destination file?

Comment: @Grateful `entries` is the files that Browserify will call when the generated script is loaded. `paths` is for a totally different purpose.

Comment: @Grateful Yep. `entries` specifies the modules that are loaded and invoked when the bundle loads. Those modules can `require` others and the `paths` option relates to the resolution mechanism used for those other modules. Not all modules need to be specified as `entries` - only the module (or modules) that bootstrap the app, so to speak.

Comment: @cartant Oh wait.... I need to understand that better. Did you just say that "not all modules need to be specified"... first of all, I thought any javascript file that you needed to be concatenated, uglified and bundled (class or no class, module or no module, require or no require) should be referenced in `entries`... so can you elaborate on what you mean by "module" and more specifically "only the modules (or modules) that bootstrap the app"?

Comment: If the code that starts the app is in module `a` and module `a` requires module `b` which requires module `c`, you only need to specify module `a` as the entry point. Browserify will examine the `require` dependency tree and will include all dependent modules in the bundle. You don't have to specify them all, just the entry point - of which there is often only one (unless you are bundling tests, in which case each test is often added as an entry point, too).

Comment: @cartant Oh I see... that makes more sense. However, I now have a slight problem. I programmed my application in a way that instead of creating modules and requiring them... I simply created various functions in various files and referenced each of this files (containing the functions) in my html file. In this case.. what should I add to my `entries`?

Comment: If that's what you are doing, you won't be getting the most out of Browserify. And, yes, you will need to add all of your files to `entries` and you will need to get the order correct. You should seriously consider switching to using `require` so that you don't have to manage dependencies yourself.

Comment: @cartant Yes... now that you have made it clearer for me... I see what's lacking. Unfortunately, time is too tight for me to make a switch right now. So, I guess I will have to use `require("glob")` to help me reference all those files for now (and I guess I still won't be needing `paths` yet). Apart from that... can you also kindly clarify something else... I have a few independant javascript utility libraries that I have created, that have nothing to do with "bootstrapping", but I do use them throughout the application... can I also include these files within the entries?

Comment: There is no guarantee that globbing will include your files in the necessary order. If you dependencies between files are order-sensitive, you will have problems.

Comment: @cartant okay thanks.. that's another point clarified.. however, can you kindly confirm that generally speaking... since in most cases I will want my javascript files (whether they help bootstrap my app or not) uglified and bundled etc... I should treat them all this way and include them within browserify entries.. correct?

Comment: Think about it this way: Browserify needs at least one JavaScript file as an *entry*. It examines the *entry* file's required dependencies - and the dependencies' required dependencies, etc. - and includes them in the bundle. If you have any JavaScript files that are *not required dependencies* of the entry file, you will have to *explicitly* specify them as *additional entries* for them to be included in the bundle. And the order will be important: Browserify will run the entries in the order specified.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one simple answer seems to be the fact that `**/*` is not recognised by browserify! You would have to `require("glob")` to do that... but it's probably simpler just to use `paths` to specify the extra folders.